# How to find the limit of $\lim_{n\to\infty}(n\sin\frac{n\pi}{2}\cos\frac{1}{n})$

Tags: limits, trigonometry

how do I prove that the limit for this expression
$\lim_{n\to\infty}(n\sin\frac{n\pi}{2}\cos\frac{1}{n})$
doesn't exist?

Comment: that's impossible

Comment: @clark Why would it be impossible? The expression has some zeroes and some values that diverge to $\infty$...

Comment: We have $a_n=n\sin\left(\frac{\pi n}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$. Look at the subsequences $a_{2k}$ and $a_{2k+1}$.

Comment: @5xum oops I misread the question I thought it was $1/n$ inside $\sin $ as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic strategy for showing that limits of this kind do not exist is to approach infinity along a different path; usually we consider what happens as $n$ approaches $\infty$ from the evens and the odds. I've provided an example of how to do this with your problem as provided below.

First note that as $n \to \infty$, $1/n \to 0$ so $\cos(1/n) \to 1$; moreover, since $\cos(1/n) = \cos(1) > \cos(\pi/2) = 0$ we have that $\cos(1/n) > 0$ for every $n \geq 1$. Now note that 
$$ \sin(n\pi/2) = \begin{cases} \pm1 & n \equiv 1,3 \mod{4}\\
 0 & n \equiv 0, 2 \mod{4} \end{cases}$$
so if we take $n \to \infty$ with $n = 2m$ then
$$ 2m\sin\left(\frac{2m\pi}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{1}{2m}\right) = 2m\cos\left(\frac{1}{2m}\right)\sin(m\pi) = 0$$
while if we take $n \to \infty$ with $n$ odd, then
$$ \left\lvert n\sin\left(\frac{n\pi}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{1}{n}\right) \right\rvert = \left\lvert (2k+1)\sin\left(\frac{(2k+1)\pi}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{1}{2k+1}\right) \right\rvert = \left\lvert (2k+1)\cos\left(\frac{1}{2k+1}\right) \right\rvert$$
which evidently approaches $\infty$ as $k \to \infty$. Since we have approached $\infty$ along two different paths (namely $n$ even and $n$ odd) that produce different values, we conclude that the limit does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

You could prove by contradiction. Suppose the limit exists; then use the fact that $\lim_{n \to \infty} f(n)g(n) = \lim_{n \to \infty} f(n)\lim_{n \to \infty} g(n)$ as follows:

$$\begin{align}\lim_{n \to \infty} n \sin{\frac{n\pi}{2} \cos{\frac{1}{n}}} &= \lim_{n \to \infty} \left( n \sin{\frac{n\pi}{2}} \right) \times \lim_{n \to \infty} \cos \frac{1}{n}\\ 
&= \lim_{n \to \infty} \left( n \sin{\frac{n\pi}{2}} \right) \end{align}$$

However, the sine term oscillates between -1 and 1, while $n$ goes to infinity, so the limit doesn't exist, which gives us a contradiction to our assumption that the limit exists, i.e. it follows that the limit does not exist.

(If you need to formally prove that the RHS limit does not exist, consider the cases when $n$ is even/odd, i.e. look at subsequences where $n=2k$ and $n=2k+1$.)

Answer (score 0):

In order for the limit to exist, it must approach a real number L. Separate each part of the multiplication out, because this is a limit property that you can use. So $n$ by itself is going to approach infinity. $cos(1/n)$ is going to approach 1. $sin(n\pi/2)$ is going to oscillate, so there is no limit. From this you can see that no limit exists.